# navigation gaurd not working properly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I store the log in status of the user in my store.js (using vuex for state management)
When the user is logged in the login status is set to true in store.js

I check if the user is logged in and using **v-if** i hide the login button . Till he everything works fine

Now for checking purpose i removed the **v-if** condition on login button
I set up á before enter navigation guard in my **!ogin.vue** component as below

**login.vue**

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
         next(vm => {
            if(vm.$store.getters.g_loginStatus === true){
                next('/');
            }else{
                next(); 
            }
         })
    }
```

If the user is logged in and presses the login button he is redirected to the home page

This works fine as the navigation guard is set up.

**but the problem arises** when i directly type in the login component url (localhost:8080/login) in the search.

The login component gets loaded normally without getting redirected to home page...

Why does this happen¿ Am i doing something wrong

I enen tried another approach using **route meta fields** following the documentation at [route meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html)

But same problem
**when i type the direct url to login component in search not getting redirected**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({

state: {
loggedIn: false,
userName: 'Guest',
error: {
    is: false,
    errorMessage: ''
},
toast: {
    is: false,
    toastMessage: ''
}
},

getters: {
g_loginStatus: state => {
    return state.loggedIn;
},
g_userName: state => {
    return state.userName;
},
g_error: state => {
    return state.error;
},
g_toast: (state) => {
    return state.toast;
}
},
mutations: {
m_logInUser: (state) => {
    state.loggedIn = true;
},
m_loggedOut: (state) => {
    state.loggedIn = false;
}
},
actions: {
a_logInUser: ({state, dispatch}, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.e, user.p).then(
            () =>{
                resolve(dispatch('a_authStateObserver'));   
            }, error => {
                state.error.is = true;
                let errorCode = error.code;
                let errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                    state.error.errorMessage = 'Wrong password.';
                } else {
                    state.errorMessage = errorMessage;
                }
            }
        );
    });

},
a_loggedOut: () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        dispatch('a_authStateObserver');    
    });
},
a_signUpUser: ({state, dispatch}, user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.e, user.p).then(
            (u) =>{
                let uid = u.uid;
                resolve(dispatch('a_authStateObserver'));   
            }, error => {
                state.error.is = true;
                let errorCode = error.code;
                let errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                    state.error.errorMessage = 'Wrong password.';
                } else {
                    state.errorMessage = errorMessage;
                }
            }
        );
    });

},
a_authStateObserver: ({commit, state}) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            state.userName = user.email;
            state.error.is = false;
            commit('m_logInUser');
        } else {
            // User is signed out.
            commit('m_loggedOut');
        }
    });
}
```

}
    });

**login.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form_bg center-block">
        <form @submit.prevent="loginUser">
             <h3 class="text-center">Log in</h3>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input v-model="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input v-model="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">  
                </div>
               <div class="align-center">
               <p class="error" v-if="g_error.is">{{ g_error.errorMessage }}</p>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block">Log in</button>
             </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <p style="display:inline-block">Don't have an account?</p>
        <router-link to="/signup" tag="a" style="display:inline-block">Sign up</router-link>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    },
    methods: {
        loginUser(){
            this.$store.dispatch('a_logInUser', {e: this.email, p: this.password}).then(() =>{
                this.$router.replace('/statuses');

            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'g_error'
        ])
    },
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
         next(vm => {
         console.log(vm.$store.getters.g_loginStatus);
            if(vm.$store.getters.g_loginStatus === true){
                next('/');
            }else{
                next(); 
            }
         })
    }
}
```

```
**routs.js**

import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import Users from './components/user/Users.vue'
import Statuses from './components/user/Statuses.vue'
import Post from './components/Post.vue'
import UserStatus from './components/user/UserStatus.vue'
import Signup from './components/auth/Signup.vue'
import Login from './components/auth/Login.vue'

export const routes = [
{path: '/', component: Home, name:'home'},
{path: '/users', component: Users, name:'users'},
{path: '/statuses', component: Statuses, name:'statuses'},
{path: '/current', component: UserStatus, name:'currentUser'},
{path: '/signup', component: Signup, name:'signup'},
{path: '/login', component: Login, name:'login'},
{path: '/post', component: Post}
```

];

Comment: Do you even have something in the $store when you directly type the URL in the browser? Perhaps you don't and that's the cause the login component gets loaded: you actually need to log in!

Comment: Yup after login i change the loginstatus to true in my store

Comment: But the store resets when you enter your app, and that happens every time you enter the URL in the browser. Try to console.log(vm.$store.getters.g_loginStatus) before the "if" statement.

Comment: @Potray so what is the process that i should follow,,,,does this even happen in production app

Comment: That depends on what do you want to achieve. If you want the user to log in every he enters in your app, then it seems you arleady achieved that. If you the user to automatically log in in your app when he enters, you would need to store some data in browser's local storage (like a token or something), load that data when the app starts, and process it.

Comment: @Potray no i want the user to login everytime he/she visits.....so how do i know the procedure i used works cuz i cant test it as it does not work

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle, specify exactly what you want to achieve and then we can test what and why doesn't work.

Comment: @Potray i am using vuecli,,,,and it would be a lot of editing to put it in jsfiddle